# MediaPlayer not calling OnPreparedListener after setting DataSource as URL

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using media player to play a mp3 from URL.But my media player not calling OnPreparedListener after I am setting a URL as my data source. And I called PrepareAsync(). The URL is working in the browser. And I am not getting any errors.So please help me.

This is the way I am setting liseners. And I implemented all.

```
 mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
```

And this is my ErrorListener

```
//Handle errors
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        //Invoked when there has been an error during an asynchronous operation.
        switch (what) {
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
                Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR NOT VALID FOR PROGRESSIVE PLAYBACK " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
                Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR SERVER DIED " + extra);
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
                Log.d("MediaPlayer Error", "MEDIA ERROR UNKNOWN " + extra);
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And this is my OnPreparedListener

```
 @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //Invoked when the media source is ready for playback.
        startMedia();
    }
```

Comment: Not calling OnPreparedListner means onPrepared not getting called. You need to setOnpreparedListner before. Are you doing that? Show us a little code.

Comment: for getting error use setOnErrorListener and you will get an error on onError if something wrong goes.

Comment: mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

Comment: This is the way I am setting listeners.

Comment: use exomedia library for play audio from url [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410493/3536264)

Comment: Ok. I will check it.

Comment: Ya ,It's working fine now.Thank you.

Comment: What was the error/fix?

Comment: @krishan - There was no error in my code. I just changed my mediaplayer to Exomedia library.Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: exomedia library is updated now. Use the latest.There are some changes in the implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using ExoAudioPlayer I fixed the Issue.